# React jquery ajax will not update state

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I set initial state in constructor and initiate a ajax call and in success setState the new date. I render the {this.state.anything} and it will not change the state. I tried this:

```
export class Iconpack extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            first_price_string: '',
            second_price_string: ''
        }
    }

    doSomthingforgodsake () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '...',
            data: '...',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({

                    first_price_string: data.data[0].open_price,
                    second_price_string: data.data[0].high_price
                })
            }.bind(this)
        })
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.doSomthingforgodsake()
    }

    render () {
        const firstpricethatthereis = this.state.first_price_string
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='b1-icon' >
                    <p className='b1-price b1-first' >
                        { firstpricethatthereis }
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you console.log(data) do you get anything? Are you sure you want to do a  'POST' instead of a 'GET' request?

Comment: When i console.log i see the data. And yes i must POST the request.

Comment: Maybe this could be a scope issue. Maybe try taking off .bind(this) at the send of set state, and instead doing "var self = this", then doing "self.setState({...code.})"

Comment: In the constructor i did: this.doSomthingforgodsake = this. doSomthingforgodsake.bind(this) and remove the bind at the end of success. it did not work. But where do you suggest i set self = this?

Comment: right under function(data)

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: No. Nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm very strange. This really looks like either a scope issue where this is not properly set or the data object being received is not being accessed correctly.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your code. I have [created a test here](https://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/rc9xmuLb/)  which is quite similar to yours. Take a look and see if that helps.